# GL_EXT_shadow_samplers killing my shader

Tags: shaders, opengl-es2, shadow-mapping, fragment-shader

I have the following fragment shader for my scene

```
#extension GL_EXT_shadow_samplers : require
...
vec4 color = texture2D(uTextureUnit0, varTexCoord0);

if (colorTransformEnabled != 0) {
    vec3 transformedColor = colorTransform * color.rgb;
    color = vec4(transformedColor, color.a);
}
gl_FragColor = color;
```

this works like expected.

Now I add this line:

```
float shadow = shadow2DProjEXT(uShadowTexture, varShadowCoord);
```

and boom my shader does not produce any output at all.
`GL_COMPILE_STATUS` and `GL_LINK_STATUS` do not return any error messages. Any idea where to go from here to debug this?

Edit:

I'm on iOS and GL_EXT_shadow_samplers is supported.

Edit:

I forgot to check for error at some point. Now I get a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` on `glDrawElements`. Any idea what could cause this problem? Since I do not get the error when I don't use the `shadow2D` functions.

Edit:

The following state change overview might help some more:
[image: a busy cat]

Where GL_TEXTURE0+1 is the depth texture and GL_TEXTURE0 is the objects texturea

Edit:

I found out that it produces the error as soon as the shader contains a call to shadow2DProj the invalid operation error is thrown. Although the shadow2DProj function is never called in the shader. And it still throws the error if shadow2DProj is called.

Comment: is 'shadow' used anywhere?

Comment: no it's not, but i just checked if I e.g. do `color.r = shadow * color.r;` i still got nothing

Comment: If it's not used anywhere, the shader compiler should optimize the whole line out.. sounds like a driver bug, and a rather odd one.

Comment: That does not seem to be the case. Since it still produces no output even when the result is used.

Comment: GL_INVALID_OPERATIONS has a lot of meanings, can you check for the exact error code that it returns? http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glDrawElements.xml (Errors)

Comment: How can I get a more detailed error then what glGetError returns? And it returns 0x0502 and that is GL_INVALID_OPERATION

Answer (score 1):

The problem was, that the texture was not correct mapped to the shader. There was a check for the type of texture before calling glUniform1iv that ignored the shadow map.